# How to only interact with objects that are after specific object value in Json using Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm collecting data that is added to a JSON sequentially, but since they are all added together, they don't come well separated, so I need to get around this difficulty.

My JSON follows this pattern:

```
{
    "content": {
      "matchFacts": {
        "events": {
          "events": [
            {
              "type": "Substitution",
              "time": 33
            },
            {
              "type": "Card",
              "time": 34
            },
            {
              "type": "Goal",
              "time": 38            
            },
            {
              "type": "Card",
              "time": 43            
            },
            {
              "type": "AddedTime",
              "time": 45
            },
            {
              "type": "Goal",
              "time": 45
            },
            {
              "type": "Half",
              "time": 45
            },
            {
              "type": "Substitution",
              "time": 46
            },
            {
              "type": "Substitution",
              "time": 58
            },
            {
              "type": "Substitution",
              "time": 58
            },
            {
              "type": "Goal",
              "time": 71
            },
            {
              "type": "Substitution",
              "time": 74
            },
            {
              "type": "Substitution",
              "time": 74
            },
            {
              "type": "Substitution",
              "time": 77
            },
            {
              "type": "Substitution",
              "time": 77
            },
            {
              "type": "Substitution",
              "time": 77
            },
            {
              "type": "Substitution",
              "time": 83
            },
            {
              "type": "AddedTime",
              "time": 90
            },
            {
              "type": "Card",
              "time": 90
            },
            {
              "type": "Half",
              "time": 90
            }
          ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say I need to collect only the `"type": "Goal"` that are before the first `"type": "Half"` appears, so I do it like this:

```
search_goals = response_json['content']['matchFacts']['events']['events']
goals_ht = 0
for event in search_goals:
    if (event['type'] == 'Half'):
        break
    elif (event['type'] == 'Goal'):
        goals_ht += 1
```

But what about when I need to collect only `"type": "Goal"` that are AFTER the first `"type": "Half"`, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your structure, a possible solution is to create a `False` flag that flips to `True` once a `Half` event is reached, then simply check for that flag when doing something to the `Goal` events:

```
search_goals = response_json['content']['matchFacts']['events']['events']

reached_ht = False
for event in search_goals:
    if event['type'] == 'Half':
        reached_ht = True
    elif event['type'] == 'Goal' and reached_ht:
        # ...
```

Comment: Hello @jfaccioni, thanks in advance for trying to help me. It's not reliable to do it this way because if a ```Goal``` is exactly in ```45``` after ```Half```, it won't count and if I put ```>=``` it can count twice, once before ```Half``` and after ```Half```. Did you understand the problem with this option?

Comment: @BrondbyIF I edited my answer, you can also achieve this with a `False`/`True` flag that flips once the `Half` event is reached.

Comment: Good approach, thank you very much for the recommendation! I thought of doing it using the time counter that appears, ```0``` for goals before half time and ```1``` for after the half time, but your model was much faster